# Python can make alphabet list like Haskell?

Tags: python

Haskell can this:

```
['a'..'z']
```

In Python:

```
map(chr, range(97, 123))
```

I feel Python is something verbose.
Have Python another easy way like Haskell?

Comment: This construct is common in Perl and it is addictive. I wish Python had it...

Comment: Verbose is not necessarily a bad thing. Although I wouldn't call that verbose. A clearer way to right that would be `[chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)]`.

Comment: Also I believe ruby has this as well.

Comment: In Perl, it is the [range operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators). Very addictive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. `from string import ascii_lowercase`.

Answer (score 6):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
L = list(ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: It works both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Oh, woops, funny I was testing it on my computer doing some slightly different code and that's why it didn't work for me on Python 3 xD

Answer (score 6):

A slightly more readable version without importing anything

```
alphabet = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic way, because syntax `[a..b]` in haskell uses special typeclass [Enum](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/Prelude.html#t%3aEnum), but there is no special magic methods or special syntax for enumeration in python.

Comment: Also, although I can think of *some* uses for this syntax, most potential use cases are completely covered by `range(start, stop, step)` in python.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want it as a list, then you can do the following:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
l = [i for i in ascii_lowercase]
```

Comment: Or just `list(ascii_lowercase)`.