# How to make a continuous alphabetic list python (from a-z then from aa, ab, ac etc)

Tags: python, sequence, enumerate, alphabetical

I would like to make a alphabetical list for an application similar to an excel worksheet.

A user would input number of cells and I would like to generate list.
For example a user needs 54 cells. Then I would generate

'a','b','c',...,'z','aa','ab','ac',...,'az', 'ba','bb'

I can generate the list from [[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032035/python-can-make-alphabet-list-like-haskell)

```
 from string import ascii_lowercase
 L = list(ascii_lowercase)
```

How do i stitch it together?
A similar question for PHP has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958518/how-to-list-from-a-to-z-in-php-and-then-on-to-aa-ab-ac-etc). Does some one have the python equivalent?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import itertools

def iter_all_strings():
    for size in itertools.count(1):
        for s in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(s)

for s in iter_all_strings():
    print(s)
    if s == 'bb':
        break
```

Result:

```
a
b
c
d
e
...
y
z
aa
ab
ac
...
ay
az
ba
bb
```

This has the added benefit of going well beyond two-letter combinations. If you need a million strings, it will happily give you three and four and five letter strings.

---

Bonus style tip: if you don't like having an explicit `break` inside the bottom loop, you can use `islice` to make the loop terminate on its own:

```
for s in itertools.islice(iter_all_strings(), 54):
    print s
```

Comment: anyway i could say start at hhhh

Comment: This is brilliant. Good job sir.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
L = list(ascii_lowercase) + [letter1+letter2 for letter1 in ascii_lowercase for letter2 in ascii_lowercase]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to get the one letter combinations 'a', 'b', etc

Comment: Ok, but what if the user needs more than 702 different strings? They'll need to go beyond 'zz' into 'aaa'.

Comment: fair enough ... i didn't understand that from your question

Answer (score 2):

Following @Kevin 's answer :

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
import itertools

# define the generator itself
def iter_all_strings():
    size = 1
    while True:
        for s in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(s)
        size +=1
```

The code below enables one to generate strings, that can be used to generate unique labels for example.

```
# define the generator handler
gen = iter_all_strings()
def label_gen():
    for s in gen:
        return s

# call it whenever needed
print label_gen()
print label_gen()
print label_gen()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up doing my own.
I think it can create any number of letters.

```
def AA(n, s):
    r = n % 26
    r = r if r > 0 else 26
    n = (n - r) / 26
    s = chr(64 + r) + s

    if n > 26: 
        s = AA(n, s)
    elif n > 0:
        s = chr(64 + n) + s

    return s
```

`n = quantity` | `r = remaining (26 letters A-Z)` | `s = string`

To print the list :

```
def uprint(nc):
    for x in range(1, nc + 1):
        print AA(x,'').lower()
```

Used VBA before convert to python :

```
Function AA(n, s)

    r = n Mod 26
    r = IIf(r > 0, r, 26)
    n = (n - r) / 26
    s = Chr(64 + r) & s

    If n > 26 Then
        s = AA(n, s)
    ElseIf n > 0 Then
        s = Chr(64 + n) & s
    End If

    AA = s

End Function
```

Comment: This works really well. It should be noted that the line in the AA function `n = (n - r) / 26` should use floor division (as in, `n = (n - r) // 26`) in Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Using neo's insight on a while loop.
For a given iterable with chars in ascending order. 'abcd...'.
n is the Nth position of the representation starting with 1 as the first position.

```py
def char_label(n, chars):
    indexes = []
    while n:
        residual = n % len(chars)
        if residual == 0:
            residual = len(chars)
        indexes.append(residual)
        n = (n - residual)
        n = n // len(chars)
    indexes.reverse()
    label = ''
    for i in indexes:
        label += chars[i-1]
    return label
```

Later you can print a list of the range n of the 'labels' you need  using a for loop:

```py
my_chrs = 'abc'
n = 15
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(char_label(i, my_chrs))
```

or build a list comprehension etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string in this sequence and want to find the next one, the following approach may be useful:

```
def get_next_seq(prev_seq):
    # '@' is the character before 'A' and is used as a zero padding
    # '[' is the character after 'Z', we add one to the end as an initial 'carryover'
    seq = list('@'+prev_seq.strip()+'[')
    for i in range(1,len(seq)):
        if seq[-i] == '[':
            seq[-i] = 'A'
            seq[-(i+1)] = chr(ord(seq[-(i+1)])+1)
    # Remove leading zero ('@') if still present
    seq = ''.join(seq).replace('@','')
    # Also remove the carryover character at the end
    return seq[:-1]
```

Result:

```
>>> get_next_seq('')
'A'
>>> get_next_seq('ZZ')
'AAA'
>>> get_next_seq('ABC')
'ABD'
```

Basically we treat the character string like a number and increment it. This will work with strings of any length and avoids the generation of long lists when only a small subset is required.

Answer (score 0):

Print the set of xl cell range of lowercase and uppercase charterers

Upper_case:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import itertools
def iter_range_strings(start_colu):
    for size in itertools.count(1):
        for string  in itertools.product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(string)

input_colume_range = ['A', 'B']
input_row_range= [1,2]
for row in iter_range_strings(input_colume_range[0]):
    for colum in range(int(input_row_range[0]), int(input_row_range[1]+1)):
        print(str(row)+ str(colum))
    if row ==  input_colume_range[1]:
        break
```

Result:

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
```

Answer (score 0):

In two lines (plus an import):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as ABC

count = 100
ABC+=' '
[(ABC[x[0]] + ABC[x[1]]).strip() for i in range(count) if (x:= divmod(i-26, 26))]
```

Wrap it in a function/lambda if you need to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
for i in range(len(alphabet)):
    for a in range(len(alphabet)):
        print(alphabet[i] + alphabet[a])
```

result:

```
aa
ab
ac
ad
ae
af
ag
ah
ai
aj
ak
al
am
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).