# How to create an iterator with Python itertools that returns progressively larger repeats?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to create an iterator that returns progressively larger products of another iterator, i.e., return first the products with repeat=1, then repeat=2, and so on. In code, it would be:

```py
infinite_product('AB')
-> ('A'), ('B'), ('AA'), ('AB'), ('BA'), ('BB'), ('AAA'), ('AAB'), ('ABA')...
```

The closest function described in itertools documentation is `powerset()`, which I was unable to adapt because the iterator is supposed to be infinite and using `itertools.count()` as the `repeat` argument is not possible (`TypeError: 'itertools.count' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`).

Is it possible to do something similar with `itertools`, without writing nested loops?

Comment: Possible duplicate / related reading: [How to make a continuous alphabetic list python (from a-z then from aa, ab, ac etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29351492/953482)

Comment: Seems you'll have to nest somewhere if you are going to use itertools.product with successive values for the repeat parameter.