# Enumerate with letters instead of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Is there a way in python to perform the same function as `enumerate()` but with letters instead?

For example

```
x = ['block', 'cheese']

for i, word in enumerate(x):
    print((i, word))
```

would produce

```
(1, 'block')
(2, 'cheese')
```

Is there a straightforward way to produce this?

```
('A', 'block')
('B', 'cheese')
```

Comment: What should happen when there's > 26 elements?

Comment: @Kingsley - Good question. It should probably perform the same way Excel performs, with AA, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351492/how-to-make-a-continuous-alphabetic-list-python-from-a-z-then-from-aa-ab-ac-e

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For up to 26 elements you can do:

```
import string

x = ['block', 'cheese']

for i, word in zip(string.ascii_uppercase, x):
    print((i, word))
```

**Output**

```
('A', 'block')
('B', 'cheese')
```

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible.

But maybe `string.ascii_lowercase` could help you

```
import string
string.ascii_lowercase
>>>>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
string.ascii_lowercase[0]
>>>>> a
```

Answer (score 1):

You could relatively easy mimic `Excel`'s behaviour with a generator:

```
def mimic_excel():
    for i in range(0, 26):
        yield chr(i + 65)

    i, j = [0, 0]

    for j in range(0, 26):
        for i in range(0, 26):
            yield "{}{}".format(chr(j + 65), chr(i + 65))


for letter in mimic_excel():
    print(letter)
```

This yields

```
A
B
C
...
ZX
ZY
ZZ
```