# Generating a continuous alphabetical list (from a-z then from aa, bb, cc, ..., aaa, bbb, ccc)

Tags: swift, swift5

I have found a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351492/how-to-make-a-continuous-alphabetic-list-python-from-a-z-then-from-aa-ab-ac-e/29351603#29351603) in Python, but I'm not too experienced with itertools to replicate it in SwiftUI.

However, I'm not looking for `a...z, aa, ab, ac...`

I'm looking to generate (based on a number) the following:

`a...z, aa, bb, cc, dd..., aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd`

I've tried adding every *used* label to an array, and if it exists, I will just add another letter.

Is this bad practice? I can't find any other solutions online, and racked my brain to come up with even this simple solution.

I would love a simple generator that doesn't have to modify a state array variable, since I might need to generate hundreds and want to keep this somewhat unimportant design style from slowing my app down.

Any help is appreciated, thanks so much

UPDATE: I've come up with another solution, but wouldn't mind a better one:

```
func nextAlphabeticalLabel(list_index: Int) -> String {
    let characterset = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    var char = ""
    
    if list_index < characterset.count {
        char = "\(characterset[list_index])"
        
        return char
    }
    
    var absolute_char_index = list_index
    var times = 1
    
    while absolute_char_index > 25 {
        absolute_char_index -= 26
        times += 1
    }
    
    return String(repeating: characterset[absolute_char_index], count: times)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. SO is not a code writing service. You have to show us what you have tried, what isn’t working and what you have researched to try and solve it.

Comment: `let charIndex = index % characterSet.count`
`let times = (index / characterSet.count) + 1`. That's all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `import Algorithms` you can use [`product`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Product.md)

```
let p = product(1...,  UnicodeScalar("a").value...UnicodeScalar("z").value)
    .lazy
    .map { (i, v) -> String in
        String(repeating: String(UnicodeScalar(v)!), count: i)
    }
```

That will give you a *lazy map sequence*, e.g. take the first 1000 items:

```
for t in p.prefix(1000) {
    print(t)
}
```

Or perhaps you want to make an iterator like:

```
    var i = p.makeIterator()
```

and then use it to generate the next value with

```
    i.next()
```